# What is the diameter of skew binary trees( either left skew of right skew tree)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

```
Diameter of binary tree is defined as:-
  The longest path between 2 leaf nodes in BT.
  let left height=lht, right height=rht,
      left left diameter=ld , right diameter= rd;
  then 
      diameter= max((lht + rht + 1), max (ld,rd));
```

But in skew trees there is only one leaf node so how will we get diameter of skew trees.
is it be 0?

Comment: What is your source for this definition of *diameter*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the definition of *diameter* of a binary tree, then you obviously need two leaf nodes. So if the tree only has one leaf, the diameter is undefined according to this definition.

The definition looks suspicious though, because it makes the diameter a *path*:

> The longest path between 2 leaf nodes in BT

Surely, this is not even consistent with what follows:

> ```
> diameter = max((lht + rht + 1), max (ld,rd));
> ```

... as that defines the diameter as a number, not a path.

So at least the definition should have read:

> The **length of** the longest path between 2 leaf nodes in BT

Furthermore, the provided formula only gives a recursive relationship, without base case. Without a base case this formula is not defining anything.

So I would highlight that you've got a very shaky "definition" there...

Compare this to the following definitions of a *graph's diameter* (not necessarily a tree):

- [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html):

  > The graph diameter of a graph is the length [...] of the "longest shortest path" (i.e., the longest graph geodesic) between any two graph vertices
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)):

  > The diameter  of a graph is [...] the greatest distance between any pair of vertices [...]. To find the diameter of a graph, first find the shortest path between each pair of vertices. The greatest length of any of these paths is the diameter of the graph.
- [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-measurements-length-distance-diameter-eccentricity-radius-center/):

  > The diameter of graph is the maximum distance between the pair of vertices. [...] Way to solve it is to find all the paths and then find the maximum of all.
- [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/graph_theory/graph_theory_basic_properties.htm):

  > The maximum among all the distances between a vertex to all other vertices is considered as the diameter of the Graph G.

This definition gives the same result as the definition you quoted, as long as it concerns a tree with at least two leaves. But when the tree has just one leaf, then these definitions are not compatible. With the definition from the above sources, the diameter of a skewed binary tree would be the distance between the root and the (unique) leaf.

A boundary case would be when the tree has just one node, i.e. the root. In that case the diameter of that graph would be 0 (according to the quotes above).

Answer (score 0):

Sinch a skew tree only has one leaf so diameter won't be defined in this case as it is the longest distance between two leaves of a tree.